# One individual jQuery UI DatePicker not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have three text inputs on a view. All have the class `datepicker`.

```
@Html.TextBox("Dummy", DateTime.Now, new { @class = "datepicker" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
```

The bottom two are covered by my `DateTime` editor template:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    string editText = Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "";
}
@Html.TextBox("", editText, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

These are set up for date pickers in my `_Layout` template in the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
    });
});
```

Now the date picker popup for `StartDate`, only, is totally unresponsive. It won't even change months, never mind pick a date. All three inputs are the same. Both `StartDate` and `EndDate` are non-nullable `DateTime` fields declared as:

```
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3, both installed via NuGet. I had to include the following script to get the DatePickers working:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

I am totally stymied.

**AMENDMENT:** 
Errors show in the Javascript console:

Clicking on a day produces the error "Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined".

Clicking on the previous or next month icon produces "Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined"

Comment: So does the datepicker show up for any other inputs like EndDate or Dummy? Unresponsive as well? Also assuming no Javascript console errors?

Comment: @StevenV I quote myself from above: "the date picker popup for StartDate, *only*, is totally unresponsive." There are, however, interesting console errors. Please see my amendment to the question.

Comment: I've run into those Javascript errors when there is a duplicate ID on the page. I'd take a look at your rendered HTML and see if there's any duplicate "StartDate" IDs on the page.

Comment: Can you pull the javascript and html out and put it on jsfiddle? At least that way you can start to isolate the problem and add a link here for people to see what you've got to work with

Comment: It's strange that you would you need to include the jquery migrate plugin just to get the datepickers to work. Do you have some older jquery code on the page? It may be causing a conflict.

Comment: @rycornell I forget where Migrate was recommended, but removing it makes zero difference.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't have an unique id for the textbox?
an unique id is required for the datepicker.
either add it in the javascript

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker:not(.hasdatepicker)").uniqueId().datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
    });
});
```

or add it in razor

```
@Html.TextBox("", editText, new { @class = "datepicker", id = string.Format("datepicker-{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid()) })
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used exact version of each script file (jQuery,jQuery UI, jQuery migrate) and used your code and found no error. It works fine without any issue.

**Modal:**

```
 public class Test
    {
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit View:**

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Test

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.Cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    string editText = Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "";
}
@Html.TextBox("", editText, new { @class = "datepicker" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is the order of CSS and JS files.

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

It seems something else is causing the issue and not any script file or anything else. You might want to try my code in new project.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for more info: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

And try to change mm to MM

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/MM/dd"
    });
});
```

Second answer:

Try using this date/time picker:
http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
or 
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

I used them both, and worked for me.
Hope this helpes.

Comment: According to http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate `MM` and `mm` are valid. I doubt the entire date picker would stop working from that.

Comment: True. But I found something else. Hope this helpes.

Comment: @SanRyu, there is nothing wrong with the date picker elsewhere or in any of my projects. I would much rather find out what is wrong here than replace it for one dysfunctional instance.